# Get Events from the Android Calendar - 2.2

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a list of all events from the onboard Android calendar and use it to populate a list view in my application. How do I do this on 2.2 and above. The link below describes how to do it on <= 2.1.

[Android Calendar Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302209/android-calendar-events)

The same method doesn't seem to work on 2.2 and above though even when I change the events uri.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Burman: There is no documented and supported API for getting at events in the Calendar app. As you have noticed, these poor back-door mechanisms will change. They also may not be supported by all devices, since they do not have to honor these implementation-specific content providers. Please use the Google GData API for the Calendar if you want to work with a user's Google Calendar.

Comment: @CommonWare - I've read in numerous places that one shouldn't use the gData API with Android, but rather use the google-java-api libraries instead.  Can you confirm this?