# How to find and select events calendar in Android?

Tags: android, calendar, android-widget, android-calendar

I am trying to implement finding and selecting events in calendar on Android Application. I believe that, find and select have completely different implementation.

I have scoured the web to no avail. I would appreciate a helping hand.

Comment: what is the meaning find and select

Comment: I do not understand your question but i can try to elaborate. find event is essentially used to locate an event based on search parameters like start date, end date or description while select event is the basic selection query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
```

These examples are for <= 2.1 version;

first; find out which calendars exist

```
Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id",  "displayname" }, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String[] CalNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
int[] CalIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
for (int i = 0; i < CalNames.length; i++) {
    CalIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
    CalNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
cursor.close();
```

Fetching all events, and particular event is done by specifying range
`ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver()`;

```
Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(getCalendarUriBase() + "/instances/when").buildUpon();
        long now = new Date().getTime();
        ContentUris.appendId(builder, now - DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_DAY*10000);
        ContentUris.appendId(builder, now + DateUtils.MILLIS_PER_DAY * 10000);
```

and then let's say you wish to log events ID from calendar with ID = 1

```
Cursor eventCursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(),
                new String[] { "event_id"}, "Calendars._id=" + 1,
                null, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC"); 
        // For a full list of available columns see http://tinyurl.com/yfbg76w
        while (eventCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String uid2 = eventCursor.getString(0);
            Log.v("eventID : ", uid2);

        }
```

and for some *source code* check
[Jim Blackler's *Accessing the internal calendar database inside Google Android applications*](http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151) and [Android Calendar Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302209/android-calendar-events)

Comment: Thanks Sherif, Let me have a look at the implementation and i'll get back to you.

Comment: Sherif, the article you provided explains the selection of an event, however, what about finding an event based on a search parameter?

Comment: I edited the answer. By the way, it is rather easy

Comment: Sherif, please provide any additional information you might have. I am rather desperate.

Comment: did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302209/android-calendar-events

Comment: Sherif, not to come off inconsiderate, do you have any more information that further clarifys? thanks

Comment: I edited answer :) that is the last thing i have

Comment: @Sherif let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2054/discussion-between-user788511-and-sherif)

Comment: Thanks Sherif, I appreciate your input

Answer (score 0):

It is for 2.2+ version only

I used the code below to add event in calender

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
                    .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
                    /*
                     * .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
                     * beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
                     * .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
                     * endTime.getTimeInMillis())
                     */
                    .putExtra(Events.TITLE,
                            "A Test Event from android app by Neha ")
                    .

                    putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis())
                    .putExtra("allDay", true)
                    .putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY")
                    .putExtra("endTime",
                            cal.getTimeInMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000)
                    .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        else {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
            intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
            intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
            intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
            intent.putExtra("endTime",
                    cal.getTimeInMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
            intent.putExtra("title",
                    "A Test Event from android app by Neha");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

and the code below i used to edit event

```
long calendarEventID = GetMaxID();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events/"
                + String.valueOf(calendarEventID));

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(uri);

        intent.putExtra("beginTime", startDate);
        intent.putExtra("endTime", endDate);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and GetMaxId as

public long GetMaxID() {

```
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Uri local_uri;
    local_uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(local_uri, new String[] {
            "_id as max_id", "dtstart", "dtend" }, null, null, "_id");

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    long max_val = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("max_id"));

    startDate = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("dtstart"));
    endDate = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("dtend"));

    return max_val + 1;

}
```

and put the permission in menifest as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"></uses-permission>
```

Hope it would help to someone also.