# Week View of calendar in android

Tags: android, calendar

I am developing an Android application. Now on the click of the `Spinner` the calendar will open.Now that calendar should be in week view and on click of the specific date I have to call one `Activity` as per my requirement.Anybody guide me for this.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
Calendar c;
int date;
int month;
int year;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.change_booking_date);
    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    dates = new String[7];
    date = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}
```

Increment the dates and update them accordingly.

```
public void updateDate() {
    if (date > c.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
        date = 1;
        month++;
        updateMonth();
    }
    else 
        date++;
}
public void updateMonth() {
    if (month > c.getMaximum(Calendar.MONTH)) {
        month = 1;
        year++;
    }
    else
        month++;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion. but how would i get that View which i am looking for? Like in phone there is calendar with month view like that i want week view.

Comment: you need to design custom view for that.

Comment: use 7 buttons horizontally representing days.

Comment: ok thank you and i there any way to view the events in the phone's calendar from my app? or is it possible to do so?

Comment: ya you can do that. follow this link for more info.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302209/android-calendar-events