# Android 2.3.3 Calendar API - Get Events

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I am trying to develop a simple application that polls events from a User's Calendar every X hours or minutes and turns the phone on vibrate or silent.

How can I access a list of future events?

I'm reading all over the place that there is no public Calendar API, if this is the case, how does the application "In-Meeting Manager" work? It does exactly what I want to do, and it runs on my Android 2.3.6 device.

I'm not sure where to get started in retrieving those events.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302209/android-calendar-events) and tutorial [here](http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151). [Pre-ICS the calendar API isn't public](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/10/ics-and-non-public-apis.html) but that doesn't mean that you can't use it, just that you shouldn't.