# how to get device calendar event list in android device?

Tags: android, events, calendar

I want to get calendar event last sevendays on android devices ? i am beginner so tell me step by step solution for this..!Only get and read calendar not update and delete. Anybody help me ? i used code in below!

```
public class Example {

    public static void readCalendar(Context context) {

        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

        // Fetch a list of all calendars synced with the device, their display names and whether the
        // user has them selected for display.

        final Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"),
                (new String[] { "_id", "displayName", "selected" }), null, null, null);
        // For a full list of available columns see http://tinyurl.com/yfbg76w

        HashSet<String> calendarIds = new HashSet<String>();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            final String _id = cursor.getString(0);
            final String displayName = cursor.getString(1);
            final Boolean selected = !cursor.getString(2).equals("0");

            Log.v("anim","Id: " + _id + " Display Name: " + displayName + " Selected: " + selected);
            calendarIds.add(_id);
        }

        // For each calendar, display all the events from the previous week to the end of next week.        
        for (String id : calendarIds) {
            Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse("content://calendar/instances/when").buildUpon();
            long now = new Date().getTime();
            ContentUris.appendId(builder, now - DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS);
            ContentUris.appendId(builder, now + DateUtils.WEEK_IN_MILLIS);

            Cursor eventCursor = contentResolver.query(builder.build(),
                    new String[] { "title", "begin", "end", "allDay"}, "Calendars._id=" + id,
                    null, "startDay ASC, startMinute ASC"); 
            // For a full list of available columns see http://tinyurl.com/yfbg76w

            while (eventCursor.moveToNext()) {
                final String title = eventCursor.getString(0);
                final Date begin = new Date(eventCursor.getLong(1));
                final Date end = new Date(eventCursor.getLong(2));
                final Boolean allDay = !eventCursor.getString(3).equals("0");

                Log.v("anim","Title: " + title + " Begin: " + begin + " End: " + end +
                        " All Day: " + allDay);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

i got null-pointerException.

Comment: Even you are newbie, i am sure you are not a newbie in "google search" :) Please check this already existed question: [Android Calendar Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302209/android-calendar-events)

Comment: paresh you help me !! i am tried this code used.

Comment: How to get events for google calendar accounts ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

My problem solved and i use below `code`-

```
public class Utility {
    public static ArrayList<String> nameOfEvent = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> startDates = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> endDates = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static ArrayList<String> readCalendarEvent(Context context) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                .query(
                        Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                        new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description",
                                "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation" }, null,
                        null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // fetching calendars name
        String CNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];

        // fetching calendars id
        nameOfEvent.clear();
        startDates.clear();
        endDates.clear();
        descriptions.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++) {

            nameOfEvent.add(cursor.getString(1));
            startDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3))));
            endDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4))));
            descriptions.add(cursor.getString(2));
            CNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
            cursor.moveToNext();

        }
        return nameOfEvent;
    }

    public static String getDate(long milliSeconds) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is excellent. Please tel me how to get that id("calendar_id"). i tried like this id= cursor.getString(0) ; but it gives 2 for all events.

Comment: you used for link many help for you : http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-calendarcontract-provider/

Comment: How can I get calendar events for particular date or week?

Comment: any answer will be helpfull for me?

Comment: How to sync all the google calendar events in android calendar and this code is reading only the android calendars events+ics format files only.Could any one tell me ?

Comment: Don't forget to set <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/> and if needed
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>

Comment: How to display the return value 'nameOfEvent'. When I call readCalendarEvents it asks me to put 'Context' in parentheses. Any help?

Comment: how to get List Of attendees

Answer (score 0):

Great Thanks!
However, you got all the events from only one Calendar, like your main Google Account, how can you get events from ALL available calendars ??

Notice that on your built in calendar Widget, you can see events from Gmail, Exchange, Facebook etc' 
How to get these events as well?

As for particular events for date or week, I did this by using the 
the selection clause and selection Args in the query statement like this for particular day:

These are the selection and args define:

```
Uri content = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
String[] vec = new String[] { "calendar_id", "title", "description", "dtstart", "dtend", "allDay", "eventLocation" };
String selectionClause = "(dtstart >= ? AND dtend <= ?) OR (dtstart >= ? AND allDay = ?)";
String[] selectionsArgs = new String[]{"" + dtstart, "" + dtend, "" + dtstart, "1"};
```

And this how the query looks:

```
   ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
   Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(content, vec, selectionClause, selectionsArgs, null);
```

Comment: Could you please post a working code for this? It would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way for you to get all the Calendar events list.

```
public static void readCalendarEvent(Context context) {

       ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
       cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), (new String[] { "_id", "title", "organizer", "dtstart", "dtend"}), null, null, null);

       List<GoogleCalendar> gCalendar = new ArrayList<GoogleCalendar>();
        try {

            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    GoogleCalendar googleCalendar = new GoogleCalendar();
                    // event_ID: ID of tabel Event 
                    int event_ID = cursor.getInt(0);
                    googleCalendar.setEvent_id(event_ID);
                    // title of Event
                    String title = cursor.getString(1);
                    googleCalendar.setTitle(title);
                    String mOrganizer = cursor.getString(2);
                    googleCalendar.setOrganizer(mOrganizer);
                    // Date start of Event
                    String dtStart = cursor.getString(3);
                    googleCalendar.setDtstart(dtStart);
                    // Date end of Event
                    String dtEnd = cursor.getString(4);
                    googleCalendar.setDtend(dtEnd);
                    gCalendar.add(googleCalendar);
                    Log.d("CaledarM",googleCalendar.getTitle()+" name = "+googleCalendar.getOrganizer()+" dateStart = "+googleCalendar.getDtstart()+" Size = " + gCalendar.size());
                }
            }
        } catch (AssertionError ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


// class GoogleCalendar()

public class GoogleCalendar {

    private int event_id;
    private String title,
            organizer,
            dtstart,
            dtend;

    public GoogleCalendar()
    {
    }

    public int getEvent_id() {
        return event_id;
    }

    public void setEvent_id(int calendar_id) {
        event_id = calendar_id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getOrganizer() {
        return organizer;
    }

    public void setOrganizer(String description) {
        this.organizer = description;
    }

    public String getDtstart() {
        return dtstart;
    }

    public void setDtstart(String dtstart1) {
        this.dtstart = dtstart1;
    }

    public String getDtend() {
        return dtend;
    }

    public void setDtend(String dtend1) {
        this.dtend = dtend1;
    }
}
```