# Getting Calendar IDs

Tags: android, calendar, android-contentresolver

I have been trying to get the ID of the Google Calendar installed on my device with this code:

```
String[] projection =                           
                              new String[]{                         
                                    Calendars._ID,                          
                                    Calendars.NAME,                         
                                    Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,                         
                                    Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE};                            
                        Cursor calCursor =                          
                              getContentResolver().                     
                                    query(Calendars.CONTENT_URI,                            
                                          projection,                           
                                          Calendars.VISIBLE +  " = 1 ",                             
                                          null,                             
                                          Calendars._ID + " ASC");                          
                        if (calCursor.moveToFirst()) {                          
                           do {                         
                              long id = calCursor.getLong(0);                           
                              String displayName = calCursor.getString(1);                          
                              // ...
                              textView1.setText(displayName + id); //outputs display name and id

                           } while (calCursor.moveToNext());
```

But it is only returning the Name and ID of the Samsung Calendar.
Can any one explain to me why?? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// .. means you can get the other details yourself
for example

```
 long id = calCursor.getLong(0);  

 String displayName = calCursor.getString(1); 

 String descriptions = calCursor.getString(2);
```

you can add more get more details if you want..
check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069319/how-to-get-device-calendar-event-list-in-android-device)