# How to fetch calendar events from a specific calendar address in google. (Android)

Tags: html, listview, calendar, google-calendar-api, fetch

sorry but have been stuck on how i would go about fetching events from a specific calendar address that i have access too.  Im more stuck on the conceptual idea like where to start and how i would go about fetching events from this one calendar i have and display its events in a list view so who ever down loads the app can view the events of this calendar in a list view. 
I know how to fetch the calendars of the users phone and get the events from the selected users calendar and display it using text view etc. But was wondering if I could hard code in a calendar Iv created  and parse the xml or html web address so i can fetch these events and display. 
Please help! cheers

Comment: Try checking this link to retrieve calendar events from android.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302209/android-calendar-events, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069319/how-to-get-device-calendar-event-list-in-android-device

Comment: Thanks SGC will look into it… am trying to code this for 3.1(+) androids

Comment: Oh hope this makes my question above easier to understand… Is it possible to parse a google calendar address that is made public to all in my app? I want my app to be able to display the events from this public calendar address (https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/otc.school.nz_v3fcjsj7c6gaj5t0sk0ko8umj0%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic) in a list view layout. Hope this makes sense. Cheers