# Get events from public google calendar Android

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-client, calendarcontract

I would like to have a calendar view that would present all of the events of a public google calendar.
I have an OAuth 2.0 client ID for my user and my calendar is set to PUBLIC.
Then I went trough the Calendar Provider tutorial (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) and use this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Projection array. Creating indices for this array instead of doing
// dynamic lookups improves performance.
public static final String[] EVENT_PROJECTION = new String[]{
        CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,                           // 0
        CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME,                  // 1
        CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME,         // 2
        CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT                  // 3
};

// The indices for the projection array above.
private static final int PROJECTION_ID_INDEX = 0;
private static final int PROJECTION_ACCOUNT_NAME_INDEX = 1;
private static final int PROJECTION_DISPLAY_NAME_INDEX = 2;
private static final int PROJECTION_OWNER_ACCOUNT_INDEX = 3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Run query
    Cursor cur = null;
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = "((" + CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME + " = ?) AND ("
            + CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE + " = ?) AND ("
            + CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT + " = ?))";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"****@gmail.com", "google.com",
            "****@gmail.com"};
// Submit the query and get a Cursor object back.
    cur = cr.query(uri, EVENT_PROJECTION, selection, selectionArgs, null);

    // Use the cursor to step through the returned records
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        long calID = 0;
        String displayName = null;
        String accountName = null;
        String ownerName = null;

        // Get the field values
        calID = cur.getLong(PROJECTION_ID_INDEX);
        displayName = cur.getString(PROJECTION_DISPLAY_NAME_INDEX);
        accountName = cur.getString(PROJECTION_ACCOUNT_NAME_INDEX);
        ownerName = cur.getString(PROJECTION_OWNER_ACCOUNT_INDEX);
    }
}
```

}

Unfortunately, the Cursor stayed empty. I was also trying to define the ACCOUNT_TYPE to "LOCAL", but it didn't work.
Target SDK set to 21, and i have all the necessary permissions.

How can I retrieve the events of my calendar? Please help /:

Comment: You can check on these SO posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232717/how-to-get-all-the-events-from-calendar and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302209/android-calendar-events

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately I'm still stuck. My goal is to set the app so be synced with a public calendar, using an ID that i will provide. I was trying to use the OAuth 2.0 sample but it was directing the inner calendar of the device - which is not my goal. I only want to present events from a calendar that is not on the device.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get events from a public google calendar? I'm stuk on this...

Comment: Yes, but i ended up using npm. I could not find how to use the OAuth 2.0 without asking the user for a permission. I ended using my hosting for running a could function using google node.js client API.
Check out - https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis

Then:
var PublicGoogleCalendar = require('public-google-calendar')
    , publicGoogleCalendar = new PublicGoogleCalendar({ calendarId: 'blabla@gmail.com' });
publicGoogleCalendar.getEvents(function(err, events) {
  console.log(events);
});